# How to estimate the parameters of a logistic differential equation from the values of its solution at times 0, 1 and 2?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How do I solve this system of equations? I received these equations after letting Wolfram Alpha solve the logistic differential equation $$N'(t)=kN(t)(M-N(t)),\qquad N(0)=65,$$ that outputs:
$$N(t)=\frac{65Me^{kMt}}{65e^{kMt}+M-65}$$ 
I also knew that $N(1)=98$ and $N(2)=142$, which gave me this system of equations to solve for $k$ and $M$:
$$
98=\frac{65Me^{kM}}{65e^{kM}+M-65} \qquad
142=\frac{65Me^{2kM}}{65e^{2kM}+M-65}$$
I tried to solve it by hand and I also tried putting the system into Wolfram Alpha which timed out, both the free version and the Pro version.

If anyone has the digital tools or the knowledge of how to solve this by hand, I would be grateful.

Comment: Better to stick to the intermediate formula $$\frac{N(t)}{M-N(t)}=\frac{N(0)}{M-N(0)}e^{kMt},$$ which implies for example that $$\frac{N(2)}{M-N(2)}\frac{N(0)}{M-N(0)}=\left(\frac{N(1)}{M-N(1)}\right)^2.$$ Can you pursue this?

Comment: @almagest What about $M=+\frac{8134}{17}\approx+478.47$?

Comment: @Did When I last looked I could have sworn $e^{2kM}$ only occurred once, but now it seems to occur twice. So yes $M=\frac{8134}{17}$.

Comment: Thank you! That was easily solvable. However, there is nothing on this formula in my book. Where can I read more on that formula? What is it called?

Comment: Well, one just solves the differential equation, using $$(kMt)'=kM=\frac{MN'}{N(M-N)}=\frac{N'}{N}+\frac{N'}{M-N}=\left(\log|N|-\log|M-N|\right)'.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$n'(t)=kn(t)\left(m-n(t)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{n'(t)}{n(t)\left(m-n(t)\right)}=k\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{n'(t)}{n(t)\left(m-n(t)\right)}\space\text{d}t=\int k\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln\left|\frac{n(t)}{m\left(n(t)-m\right)}\right|}{m}=kt+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|\frac{n(t)}{m\left(n(t)-m\right)}\right|=\text{C}e^{mkt}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|\frac{1}{m-\frac{m^2}{n(t)}}\right|=\text{C}e^{mkt}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|m-\frac{m^2}{n(t)}\right|=\frac{\text{C}}{e^{mkt}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|1-\frac{m}{n(t)}\right|=\frac{\text{C}}{|m|e^{mkt}}$$

Now solve $\text{C}$ using $n(0)=65$:

$$\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|=\frac{\text{C}}{|m|e^{mk\cdot0}}\Longleftrightarrow\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|=\frac{\text{C}}{|m|}\Longleftrightarrow\text{C}=|m|\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|$$

So, we get:

$$\left|1-\frac{m}{n(t)}\right|=\frac{\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|}{e^{mkt}}$$

Now, when we know that $n(1)=98$ and $n(2)=142$ we get the system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left|1-\frac{m}{98}\right|=\frac{\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|}{e^{mk}}\\
\left|1-\frac{m}{142}\right|=\frac{\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|}{e^{2mk}}
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
k=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|}{\left|1-\frac{m}{98}\right|}\right)}{m}\\
\left|1-\frac{m}{142}\right|=\frac{\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|}{e^{2mk}}
\end{cases}
$$

Substitute them into eachother gives:

$$\left|1-\frac{m}{142}\right|=\frac{\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|}{\exp\left[2\cdot m\cdot\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|}{\left|1-\frac{m}{98}\right|}\right)}{m}\right]}\Longleftrightarrow\left|1-\frac{m}{142}\right|=\frac{\left|1-\frac{m}{98}\right|^2}{\left|1-\frac{m}{65}\right|}$$

And the solutions we get are:

$$m=\frac{8134}{17},k=\frac{14\ln\left(\frac{213}{130}\right)}{8134}$$

Now, we get that:

$$\left|1-\frac{8134}{17n(t)}\right|=\frac{7029}{1105\left(\frac{213}{130}\right)^{\frac{14t}{17}}}$$